# how make popup models show automaticly

Tags: javascript, popup

I want to make the popup run automatically, when the page opens, without clicking the button **show modal** , I tried to change `$(".modal_main").show();` to `$(".modal_main").false();` but I face the same problem.

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".call_modal").click(function(){
    $(".modal").fadeIn();
    $(".modal_main").show();
      });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".close").click(function(){
    $(".modal").fadeOut();
    $(".modal_main").fadeOut();
      });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button class="call_modal" style="cursor:pointer;">Show Modal</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code for showing your model is inside a click event...

Comment: so how i can repair that?

Comment: Take it outside of the click event... you know, the `$(".call_modal").click(function(){`

Comment: on page load, `document.querySelector('.modal_main').classList.add('.call_modal')` (pure JS version). (edit: the class is wrong, but you just need 2 classes, one `{ display: none; }`, one `{ display: block; }`). All you are doing is changing **when** you toggle the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the modal automaticly when the page is open you should pull it from the `.click` statement.

Additionally don't create two `.ready` statements, it isn't necessary.

You can do this like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".modal_main").show();

  $(".call_modal").click(function(){
    $(".modal").fadeIn();
    $(".modal_main").show();
  });

  $(".close").click(function(){
    $(".modal").fadeOut();
    $(".modal_main").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use two copies of document.ready.
After load page and click event attached, you should fire your click event or show div directly, like on example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".call_modal").click(function(){
 
    $(".modal").fadeIn();
    $(".modal_main").show();
      });
      
      $(".close").click(function(){
    $(".modal").fadeOut();
    $(".modal_main").fadeOut();
      });
      
      //$(".call_modal").click(); Do not use this in production code!
      $(".modal_main").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal" style="display:none">modal visible</div>
<div class="modal_main" style="display:none">main modal visible</div>

<button class="call_modal" style="cursor:pointer;">Show Modal</button>
```